# Proper syntax for "CASE WHEN ... THEN ... DELETE ... END" in SQLite triggers?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I'm trying to figure out how to put a delete statement inside a conditional in an SQLite trigger.

I've come up with this example code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN 
        1 == 1
    THEN
        DELETE FROM mytable
    END;
END;
```

But it fails to compile with:

```
Error: near "DELETE": syntax error
```

If I replace `DELETE FROM mytable` with `RAISE(FAIL, "mytrigger was activated")`, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK SQLite does not support conditional execution. The `CASE` expression is an expression(not a statement!) for conditional evaluation(not execution!). That means you can use it to choose what value to return - but not what statements to execute.

The bad news is that SQLite can't decide whether to execute the `DELETE` statement or not. The good news is that you don't really care if the `DELETE` statement is executed - you only care if the rows are deleted. So - always execute the `DELETE` statement, but make it delete rows only if your condition returns true:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM mytable
    WHERE 1 == 1
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out another way to achieve what I need - I made my trigger conditional, i.e. `CREATE TRIGGER ... WHEN ... BEGIN ... END;`. But your answer is correct for my literal question, thanks for clarifying the difference between `CASE WHEN` and `IF`, I thought it was just a synonym for `IF` for SQLite.

Comment: Actually, the `IF` function from the question you linked to(in a comment to an answer now deleted) **is** equivalent to the `CASE` expression. That `IF` is different than the regular, procedural `if` statement you know from procedural languages - it behaves more like the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#MySQL)